# Unable to forward windows host port 80 to Centos guest port 80

Tags: networking, windows-10, virtualbox, centos-7

Ok, so ive tried googling this many time already and still i am failing. I have a Windows 10 host with VirtaulBox installed. Inside my VirtaulBox i have a CentOS system installed. I have httpd running in my CentOS guest. I am using NAT as a network adapter for my VBox settings. I have already been enable to forward port 22 from my Windows host to my CentOS guest. However, when I try to forward port 80/8080/9090 from my host to my CentOS guest's port 80, I am unable to. Httpd is running fine, I have also tried different VBox adapters but it seems NAT is the way to go. My goal is to visit localhost on Chrome browser in my Windows host and be able to access my guest CentOS Apache (httpd) from there. Thanks in advance!!! I have been trying this for about a week now with no success.

Comment: as @Blackmeser said, check with netstat if the port is used on your local host (I do it with `netstat -an | findstr :80` or whatever port you want to check). Skype is one of the troublemakers as it checks if ports 80/443 are free when starting and sit on those ports if they are available. As you can forward any port to any port - you could use 8081, 9091 or whatever to forward to your VM to port 8080, 9090. It does not have to be the same port. Another thing is to check your CentOS firewall to allow all interfaces to connect to your apache server. Or (what I do most often) - see next comment:

Comment: I add a second vNIC with a host-only adapter adn connect from the host to guest using this IP, while the NATed one gives Internet access to the guests ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all processes don't using port 80. (its can be Skype, look in Skype -> config -> connection -> and disable 80/443)

Type in cmd (if in local addr not contains ***:80 - all ok):

```
netstat -ano -p TCP
```

http://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/

Or you can: in Windows host make a bridge.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537751/virtualbox-port-forward-from-guest-to-host